# Which Mercedes-Benz models are associated with this photo? There are many, I want to know them all

Tags: mercedes-benz, identify-this

This is Mercedes-Benz S600 Coupe of 2000 year.

[image: Mercedes-Benz S600 Coupe AMG]

I know there is SL50 that looks the same. What are all the models that are associated with this and look the same?

Comment: No, but then which stackexchange website is where should I ask a question? I thought this one was the most relevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to motor vehicle maintenance/repair

Comment: Welcome to the site!   Unfortunately I would have to agree with @Zaid that this question does not fall under motor vehicle/maintenance and repair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a Mercedes Benz C140 body, the coupe-version of the S-class w140 limo. For a list of the models, i.e different engines, that was made; take a look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz_W140